# (From Stata to R) Converting egen-by to R

Tags: r, stata

How could I convert this Stata command to R?

I have a database composed of individuals (each person is a row), but I also need some family variables to analyze. In this case, what I want is to identify the total amount of income earned by each family.
Each member of a family is an individual in the database, and although I don't have the individuals; identifications, I have a variable that identifies the family. .
Since I also know, for each individual, earnings in 2014, in Stata I have this command to create the variable:

```
egen family_inc = total(annual_inc), by (id_family)
```

where

`family_inc` is the total income of a family
`annual_inc` is the total income earned by the individual
`id_family` is the identification of this family in the data

So the command says to Stata:
(1) For each member of the `id_family`;
(2) Find all the members of that family;
(3) Sum the income earned during 2014;
(4) Assign this value to a new variable `family_inc`.

Could I use `group_by()` for this? I am very n00b at R. and can't spare some time to do a course now because of deadlines! `course(df_damn, mother = FALSE, explicit = 3, !is.numeric("loads of"))`

Comment: Assuming your data object in R is named dat, then do `dat %>% group_by(id_family) %>% mutate(family_inc = sum(annual_inc, na.rm=TRUE))`  Thanks @r2evans.

Comment: Used your code on iris to test and it returned this message: "
Warning message: `...` is not empty.
   
   We detected these problematic arguments: * `needs_dots`

   These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.

    Did you misspecify an argument?"

Comment: This works: `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(pl_species = sum(Petal.Length, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: what is `pl_species`? Couldn't find it on iris.

Comment: It's the name of the new variable that gets created.

Comment: Ok! Seems to work, though when using str(), it returns: $ pl_species  : num [1:150] 73.1 73.1 73.1 73.1 73.1 73.1 73.1 73.1 73.1 73.1 ...
 - attr(*, "groups")= tibble [3 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ Species: Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 2 3
  ..$ .rows  : list<int> [1:3] 
  .. ..$ : int [1:50] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. ..$ : int [1:50] 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 ...
  .. ..$ : int [1:50] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 ...
  .. ..@ ptype: int(0) 
  ..- attr(*, ".drop")= logi TRUE
Must I worry about it?

Comment: No what did you expect you would get when you did str()?

Comment: A regular "num" variable, without all those `ptype` , `attr` and `logi` stuff. I don't know what this means, but if it doesn't stop me of doing advanced survey analysis on this database, than I'll leave that way and care about what this mens after my thesis deadline. Thank you so much XD

Comment: Now, for an astonishing n00b question regarding Stack Overflow: how do I sign that this question was answered thanks to @DaveArmstrong? I would also like to thank Nick cox for helping me by editing the question.

Comment: Generally, questions that get answered in the comments don't get marked as answered.  It happens all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `Stata` code

```
webuse iris 
egen mean_petal_width = total(petwid), by(iris)
```

is equivalent to the `R` code.

```
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    mutate(
        # new_var_name   = function of other vars
        mean_petal_width = sum(Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
```

if the answer is helpful and solves the question, please mark it as solved :)

Comment: Pedantically, `mean()` is only equivalent to `total()` for samples of size 1.

Comment: Or when all observations are 0 :). I edited my answer to better respond to the original question. In my defense, however I wrote  `mean(petwid)` in the stata version as well and, therefore, R and Stata's version were equivalent. But of course, answering  the original question more closely is always better.

Comment: You got me there (smiley)  Or indeed for -1, 0, 1, and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

Stata:
`egen family_inc = total(annual_inc), by (id_family)`

My interpretation:
Generate `family_inc` equal to overall sum of `annual_inc` within each level of `id_family`

R code:

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>%
group_by(id_family) %>%
summarize(family_inc = sum(annual_inc))`
```